# Bootstrap iteration as random effect

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I have a theoretical question.

Would it make sense to replicate a dataset via bootstrapping and then perform a mixed effect analysis using the data from all iterations, specifying the specific iteration as a grouping level with random intercept and slope for the fixed effect?

Which property would confidence interval built in this way have?

Comment: Can you say more about why you would want to do this? What is it that you perceive it buys you versus bootstrapping the estimates from a mixed model on the original data?

Comment: The question is not specific for mixed model analysis. The analysis on the original data could be with any regression model also without random component. The concept is to extract the main effect by explicitly specifying the random variability due to sampling as a random effect distributed around the fixed estimate. The advantages is for example that you don't break the covariance of predictors in a mutlivariable regression, which is something that happens when you collapse estimates in bootstrap estimation. I want to explore the correctness and interpretation of conf. int. built this way.